# A good free guide to learn a object-oriented programming language

Tags: java, c++

I am sorry for this newbie question! 
I am looking for an online site where I can learn a object-oriented programming language (C++, Java). I don't know those two language of programming, so I don't know the best choice.
Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that, in spite of their insulting titles, the ***«subject» for Dummies*** series of books generally do a good job of presenting a subject in an easy-to-understand manner, starting simple, and building on early material to introduce more complex concepts. Given the specific subjects you've mentioned in your question, I suggest ***Object-Oriented Programming for Dummies***, ***C++ for Dummies***, and ***Java for Dummies***.

Comment: I am sorry I forget to say that I need a free guide.

Comment: I have rarely found a (legitimately) free guide for any subject that was worth any more than I paid for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out books by **Bruce Eckel.** They can be helpful to novices and professionals both. They are available online easily .